# How to create PROBLEMS entry in Visual Studio Code extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm building my first VSCode extension; basically I am writing a code scanner that is looking for specific patterns in the code and reporting those as problems.

I've been able to figure out how to scan the code just fine through the examples.

But I can't figure out how to report a "PROBLEM"; by this I mean I want to add an entry (appears to be a structure that includes filename, line number, message, and perhaps some other data).

Can someone point me to the documentation that describes how to do this??

Comment: You will find existing linter extensions good examples to follow, and my project chose https://github.com/hoovercj/vscode-ruby-linter . There can be other linter projects with more up-to-date code base.

Comment: Hey, thanks. That helped a little bit. So, I realize that what I need are Diagnostics. I've created my DiagnosticCollection, and add my Diagnostic to it. But I don't see anything happen in the IDE when that happens. I don't know if I need to do something with the collection? Or just the act of adding a Diagnostic instance to it?

Comment: I suggest you download and debug the ruby linter project in VSCode. It is rather simple when you set breakpoints here and there to navigate how VSCode takes care of the related objects. Once you are familiar with the workflow, you can do the same in your own extension.